# EverNote text/html content is always null when using windows sdk in Azure

Tags: azure-functions, evernote

I'm trying to get content from the Evernote sandbox environment, but I'm running into a strange issue where ever note returns null for content.

```
        ENSession.SetSharedSessionDeveloperToken("my dev key", "https://sandbox.evernote.com/shard/s1/notestore");

        if (ENSession.SharedSession.IsAuthenticated == false)
        {
            ENSession.SharedSession.AuthenticateToEvernote();
        }

        var notebooks = ENSession.SharedSession.ListNotebooks();
        var noteSearch = new ENNoteSearch(string.Empty);            

        var notes = ENSession.SharedSession.FindNotes(noteSearch, notebooks[0], ENSession.SearchScope.All, ENSession.SortOrder.RecentlyUpdated, int.MaxValue);

        var note = ENSession.SharedSession.DownloadNote(notes[3].NoteRef);
        //note.HtmlContent is null
        //note.TextContent is null
        //note.Title contains the note title
```

Comment: Why are you searching for `string.empty`

Comment: @HariHaran I'm just following what's in their documentation. I just want all notes returned. I found out more about my problem though. The SDK is not build for dotnetcore and doesn't work as expected. On top of that, Evernote doesn't officially support windows with their own .NET SDK. So I'll either have to not use dotnetcore, or figure out the issue. https://github.com/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-windows/issues/38